# In Datatables Jquery, makeEditable function, my external jquery library does not working from second page

Tags: datatables

I have input field on which token jquery library is applied means we can input multiple parameters separated by the comma (image 1), So In the first page, it is showing fine but from the second page it's not working (image 2) means from second-page class is not getting so it is not working.
In below code if I alert $('.token-input') then only 3 getting but the total is more than 10. It means that only first page elements are getting in makeEditable function.
Please help!

```
Code
makeEditable: function($element, successCallback) {
$('.token-input')
.each(function(index, element) {
...some code
}
}
```

[image: Token Jquery Input working on 1st page]

[image: Token Jquery Input not working from 2nd Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got solution...by using fnGetNodes()

```
var oTable = $('#test').dataTable();

$('.token-input', oTable.fnGetNodes())
            .each(function(index, element) {
...some code
});
```